# Multiple Databases in Vapor

Tags: postgresql, fluent, vapor

For my Vapor project, I want to mostly use a single Postgres database. However, for certain long-running requests, I want to use a separate, read-only clone of the same database.

The documentation for this is very sparse. How do I add another database connection next to the existing default database?

```swift
static func configureDatabase(_ app: Application) throws {
    try app.databases.use(.postgres(url: "postgresql://user@localhost:5432/user"), as: .psql)
}
```

When running queries, how do I tell Fluent to run those queries on the second database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The magic of multiple databases lies with the `DatabaseID`. You can define a new instance of `DatabaseID`, and register a connection with it.

```swift
extension DatabaseID {
    static let readOnly = DatabaseID("readOnly")
}

static func configureDatabase(_ app: Application) throws {
    try app.databases.use(.postgres(url: "postgresql://user@localhost:5432/user"), as: .psql)
    try app.databases.use(.postgres(url: "postgresql://user@localhost:5432/read_only"), as: .readOnly)
}
```

Then, when you want to run a query, instead of using the `request.db` database, use the `.db(_:)` method and pass in your identifier:

```swift
User.query(on: request.db(.readOnly))
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Just adding this for posterity: This question is about Vapor and Fluent Versions 4.x